# Connect to remote tmux instance inside local instance

Tags: tmux

I have a remote server that I have a detached tmux session on. I also have a local tmux instance running.

Is it possible to connect to the remote tmux session inside my local tmux session, without having a "window inside a window"?

To better explain, when I connect from my local tmux session to my remote one, I get a nested status lines, and control keys get confusing, because you're not sure which instance you're currently operating on.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do it in another terminal then.

Comment: Hi @Kent, thanks for replying. I could do that, but I was hoping to have a single set of keybindings to switch windows, aka having everything managed in tmux, versus using whatever terminals tab feature on top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sync your tmux config on the server, in another terminal, ssh into the server and tmux attach, you have same keybindings etc.

You can have nested tmux, however, it would make you lost, particularly if you have same tmux config on your server.

What you are wanting to have, it doesn't exist so far.